# Resolve a domain with another domain and not an IP address

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf

I am running some containers for automation testing and I need to be able to redirect the domain name to another domain name.

Traffic from abc.com/users need to be redirected to zxc.net/users

I cant find a solution to make a name resolution with another name such as

```
abc.com:zxc.net
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Do you mind installing your own name server?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I am running this in a container. Would like to make it as lightweight as possible. If no other solutions can I solve this by installing my own name server?

Comment: "_Traffic from abc.com/users_" - (1) do you mean "traffic addressed to abc.com/users"? (2) are you talking about webserver traffic or some other stream of data? (3) this looks like a URL, not a container

Comment: @roaima the container runs some e2e test on a website. This websites uses a backend server and I need to redirect that traffic to another backend.

Comment: So please put that in your question. It's important to explain this along with the information that you're talking about webserver redirects. Make it easy for people to have all the detail in one place.

Comment: @PatrickVibild, yes, a CNAME allows bind to do that.